# Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE error

Tags: oracle

There is UserA and UserB in my oracle.

This is the package from UserA:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkgA AS
    PROCEDURE procA 
    AS 
      l_sql = 'BEGIN ' || UserB.procB || (:l_v1,:l_v2) END;';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql USING IN l_v1,IN l_v2;
    END;
```

Thie procB is come from UserB;

When I run this, I get the error:

> PLS-00201:IDENTIFIER 'UserB.procB' must be declared;

Comment: Here is sth wrong with the quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User A need the EXECUTE right on the userb.procB.

grant the right as User B:

```
grant execute on UserB.procB to userA;
```

Comment: I use this: grant execute any procedure;Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's supplied as a parameter, the procedure name needs to be inside the string as a fixed value; you have it outside so it's trying to be interpreted as a variable name, which doesn't exist:

```
l_sql = 'BEGIN UserB.procB(:l_v1,:l_v2) END;';
```

But then you wouldn't need to execut it dynamically anyway, you could just do:

```
PROCEDURE ProcA AS
BEGIN
  UserB.procB(l_v1, l_v2);
END;
```

If you were passing the procedure as a variable, which would be a little odd, you'd have something like:

```
PROCEDURE procA (proc_name in varchar2) AS 
BEGIN
  l_sql = 'BEGIN ' || proc_name || '(:l_v1,:l_v2) END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql USING IN l_v1,IN l_v2;
END;
```

... and you'd call that as `procA('UserB.procB')`. I don't think that's what you're trying to do, but it isn't entirely clear.

In both cases you don't seem to have `l_v1` or `l_v2` defined, so I guess you've just missed that part of the code out.